# Using glimpse with NetCoreApp Framework

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

I want to use glimpse (2.0.0-beta1 NuGet package) in an ASP.NET Core Web Application using the .NET Core Framework. But NuGet ends up with the following error message:

```
error: Package Glimpse 2.0.0-beta1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Glimpse 2.0.0-beta1 supports:
error:   - dnx451 (DNX,Version=v4.5.1)
error:   - dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0)
error:   - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
error:   - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
error:   - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

The framework definition in project.json is as follows:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
```

Any option to install glimpse without building it from sources?

Comment: Which feed are you using? Have you tried this one - http://myget.org/gallery/glimpseprototype.

Comment: @anthonyv: I tried now the beta2 from glimpseprototype, but got the same error:   

Package Glimpse 2.0.0-beta2-201607261439 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Glimpse 2.0.0-beta2-201607261439 supports:
      - dnx451 (DNX,Version=v4.5.1)
      - dnxcore50 (DNXCore,Version=v5.0)
      - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
      - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
      - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but if someone else has this problem then just change showed piece of code with this one:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "netcoreapp1.0",
      "dnxcore50"
    ]
  }
}
```

where "netcoreapp1.0" is current Nuget identifier and "dnxcore50" is deprecated identifier.

Source: [.NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md)